# to extract rar file everytime asking password in 7 zip console. is there any way to give password in package?

Tags: ssis

There is a package with execute process task to extract rar files to .bak files using 7 zip. when I execute package everytime 7 zip console is prompting and asking for password. package is executing and extracting files only if I give password. is there any way to give password in package or task itself so that I no need to give manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`7z x archive.rar -psecret` will extract `archive.rar` with the password `secret`. More info here: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/password.htm